# EXPLAIN keyword, does it execute query as well or just "explains" the query?

Tags: mysql, sql

Does the EXPLAIN keyword in an INSERT or UPDATE statement execute the query, or is it just going to show ('explain') the query for you - newbie to MySQL and couldn't find the question quick enough.

Comment: It tells you the execution plan.  It doesn't execute the query (although it might execute subqueries).

Comment: Read the documentation? Define "quick enough". What is your time threshold before your own effort ends and you just get us to do your research for you?

Comment: about as fast as light racing in orbit, if that answers your question. Thanks for your response and help.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

[Reference](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/explain.html) says

> The EXPLAIN statement provides information about how MySQL executes
>   statements:

Query is not executed. Some other databases have an 'EXPLAIN ANALYZE' which actually does the explain and does the query. Mysql does not have this feature